# How to install MySQL on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, installation, mysql

Please help me how to install MySQL on Windows 7. When I tried to install, I am getting errors as:

> The security settings could not be applied to the database because the connection has failed of the following errors
>
> ERROR NR:1045
> Access denied for user 'root@'localhost(using password yes).

I tried to uninstall MySQL completely and install again, but it shows this error again and again. I have changed my firewall setting also and tried unstalling antivirus sotware too. But it also did not work.

Comment: what is your root password? does it even have a password?

Comment: Think he has just installed and doesnt know where to change

Comment: its pwd error..not Windows 7 security error..

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem, and explicitly running the MySQL installer as Administrator (right-click, select 'Run as Administrator') fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Was the provided password correct?

Otherwise please check here: http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?11,39440,417422#msg-417422

Answer (score 0):

```
# /etc/init.d/mysql stop
# mysqld_safe --user=mysql --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking &
# mysql -u root mysql
mysql> UPDATE user SET Password=PASSWORD('newpassword') where USER='root';
mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
mysql> quit

# /etc/init.d/mysql restart
# mysql -uroot -p
Enter password: <newpassword>
```

Comment: Your answer is for a linux system and in the question it has been specifically stated that the problem is in wondows

Answer (score 0):

Where you installed the mysql, there should be a file called my.cnf or my.ini, in there should be the root password .e.g

C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 4.1\my.ini